# PowerShell API query contains arithmetic operators

Tags: powershell

Note: I am not a developer, just a scripter muddling along trying to figure stuff out.

Running the following as part of a larger script

```
$sminfo = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Method Get `
  -Credential $cred `
  -Uri "https://$($APIServer)/api/6.0/ontap/snap-mirrors?relationship_type=data_protection" `
  -ContentType "application/json"
```

The object contains several sub objects, `$sminfo.result.nextTag` is the one I'm concerned with. The original value of this sub object is a string that contains `%2b` and PowerShell seems to read this as unicode and changes the string like so:

(original) `nextTag=PiM%2BMjlmNj`

(changed) `nextTag=PiM+MjlmNj`

How do I prevent PowerShell from changing the output?

Answer (score 1):

`%2B` is the URL-encoded form of the `+` characters (whose code point is `0x2B`), and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) has apparently performed decoding for you.

If you really need the encoded form:

```sh
$decoded = 'nextTag=PiM+MjlmNj'
$property, $value = $decoded -split '=', 2
$encoded = $property + '=' + [uri]::EscapeDataString($value)
```

`$encoded` then contains verbatim `nextTag=PiM%2BMjlmNj`

Note that the [`[uri]::EscapeDataString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Uri.EscapeDataString) is only applied to the *value* part (everything after `=`), because applying it to the whole string would also encode `=`, as `%3D`.

---

However, depending on how you later use the decoded value there may be no need to manually re-encode, as this (re-)encoding may happen automatically.